# Execute a function in several views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I'm still a newbie in Django and I would like to have your advices regarding this point :

I have a User system in my application which extend from userena:

```
class FindUrGeekUserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
user         = models.OneToOneField( User, unique = True, verbose_name    ='userData', related_name='myProfile',db_index = True)
type         = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = USER_TYPE, blank = True, null = True, db_index = True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return 'Name: ' + self.user.username + ' Type: ' + self.type
```

When a User registers in my website he completes login, password and email fields.

The first time a user will connect though my website, he will see a page asking him what's his usertype : Type1 or Type2...

I want to verify in each login_registered view that the user has defined his type. Until now, i created a function I use in every registered view:

```
def checkUserType(user):
    if(user.type != None)
        return True
    else:
        retur False

@login_registered
def myView(request):
    if (checkUserType(request.user)):
        Continue....
    else:
        return redirect('setUserType')  # Page where the user will set his type
```

Is there a better way to that in Django? Using some built in function ?

Thanky ou for your help

Comment: Why are `blank` and `null` true if you want to require a value?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want different function to check a flag/value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least a better way:

```
@login_registered
def myView(request):
    if not checkUserType(request.user):
        return redirect('setUserType')  # Page where the user will set his type

    # user has the type, continue
```

Also, you could [write a custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#writing-your-own-middleware), and do the check/redirect in `process_request()`. It could look like:

```
from django import http
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class SetUserTypeMiddleware(object):
    urls = ['/some/path/that/requires/user/type/',]

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return

        for url in urls: # customize url matching to your taste
            if url in request.path_info:
                return http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('setUserType'))
```

Middleware is a cool feature, it's simple and powerful. Just don't forget to register them in `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: Wow it works just great !! Is it possible to use url_name instead of hardcoded urls in the middleware ?

Comment: Yes, hence the comment "# customize url matching to your taste" :D